# Is possible to use regex with @RabbitListener queues?

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-rabbit

I haven't found anything similar, so I ask here in case someone knows if it possible.

The scenario is simple, suposse a project using Spring Boot and RabbitMQ; to listen queues you have something like this:

```java
@RabbitListener(queues = "example-queue")
public void receiveQueueMessage(String message) {
    System.out.println("[x] Received: '" + message + "'");
}
```

So, is there a way to use regex in a way similar to this?:

```java
@RabbitListener(queues = \queue\)
public void receiveQueueMessage(String message) {
    System.out.println("[x] Received: '" + message + "'");
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No; RabbitMQ does not support RegEx for queue names.

You can use the management plugin's REST API to get a list of queues and add them to the container manually (`container.addQueueNames(...)`).

Using a Direct message listener container is more efficient for that; see [Choosing a Container](https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/current/reference/html/#choose-container).